# Matlab passing in single quotations

Tags: arrays, bash, matlab

I would like to know how to pass single quotations as an argument in matlab. I am running a bash script that takes in a string of integers and creates an array from it. The bash program is like this:

```
read -a array <<< "$1"
for i in ${array[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
```

In the matlab GUI I want to test this function by doing this:

```
>> string = '1 2 3 4 5'
>> unix(['script.sh ' string])
```

and it gives

```
1

ans =

 0
```

but it does not print out the entire array! In bash if I do...

```
script.sh '1 2 3 4 5'
```

I get

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

My theory is that matlab is taking in the numbers, and the bash script is just reading the first argument '1' into the array and printing it. So if I could somehow pass the string encapsulated by single quotations then it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Matlab's `unix()` command only returns a status variable by default. You have to tell it to return the standard output as well, which is mentioned in [the Matlab documentation for this function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unix.html). The `0` value you are seeing is the status variable, and `0` means "success."

What you want to do is:

```
 [status, result] = unix(['script.sh ' string]);
 disp(result);
```

Also, [here is a link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Strings) that helps explain string formatting in Matlab and includes the example of adding a single quote into a string. This is achieved by repeating the single quote symbol twice consecutively inside the string. So '''' yields `'`, because inside of the two outer single-quotes, I have placed two consecutive single quotes. This is different than using the double-quote keystroke on the keyboard, which produces a double quote. So you can write the array string as:

```
>> string = '''1 2 3 4 5'''
string = '1 2 3 4 5'
```

Comment: If you look at the original post you can see that it is echoing back '1'. I think this technique is mostly used if you plan on saving the stdout. But I need a way to pass single quotations through to the bash script.

Comment: I see I posted just as you edited haha, Thats exactly what I needed, thanks man :)